# Eclipse write to console

Tags: eclipse, console

In Eclipse, how can I write a debug statement to a console window? I tried:

```
System.out.print(urls);

System.out.println(urls);       

Log.d("tag", urls);
```

But I don't see the values being displayed anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it's very frustrating.  Everything is enabled properly, but the output is not going to the console.  Did you find a solution?  Are you running under Win7 by any chance?  I am wondering if it is something specific to Win7.

Comment: Where are your streamouts set? I ran to this same problem because it was streaming out to a file without me knowing and then I had to System.setout() get it streaming to the right place.

Answer (score 6):

Create a console and write to it. When a console is created, you give it a name. That way your console output can be kept separate from other plugin's console output. See this article for details.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F

Comment: The link didn't work for me when clicking or copy-pasting it (I blame that `%3F` on the end). The page does exist though, you might just have to Google for it: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?q=FAQ%20How%20do%20I%20write%20to%20the%20console%20from%20a%20plug-in%3F#q=FAQ+How+do+I+write+to+the+console+from+a+plug-in%3F

Comment: I found correct link which uses https https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in_%3F

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you have the console window in eclipse setup to display output?  On the menu bar in eclipse, go to Window->Show View->Console. When you run the program, that console window should be where your System.out.print(ln) output is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running some kind of client-server application, you may actually have multiple consoles. If you see a console, there should be a little arrow icon next to it. Use that to dropdown a list of all the various consoles, and pick the appropriate one.

Answer (score 3):

My output goes to the LogCat tab, not the Console.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running any class having main method and want to print logs on eclipse console, then create a file "log4j.properties" in src/main/resources

If you want to print log in your test classes then put this file in src/test/resources.

***log4j.properties***

> ```
> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DEBUG, WARN, ERROR, stdout
>
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%C:%L] [%t] - %m%n
>
> log4j.logger.backtype.storm=DEBUG
> log4j.logger.clojure.tools=DEBUG
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to switch between client and server outputs in eclipse. Please see the screenshot which shows an option to toggle between the console outputs.

[Eclipse screenshot to show console option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJNE3.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this , it will output in console tab

```
System.out.print("Hello World ..... !");       
// Redirect the stdout and stderr to the LogPanel
SystemLogger out = new SystemLogger(System.out, Level.INFO);
SystemLogger err = new SystemLogger(System.err, Level.ERROR);
System.setOut(out);
System.setErr(err);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code is in Java? If you want to use a logger that will print out to your console similarly to "system.out.println();", add java.util.logging to your eclipse project. `import java.util.logging.Logger;`

Then inside each class where you want output to your console, add `private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(<your_class_name>.class.getName());` replacing  with your class name.

And where you want console output, put a line in that part of your class like `LOG.info("code got to this point!");` similarly to how you would use system.out.println();

I only use the logger instead of `system.out.println();` statements because the logging seems more professional. And frankly the logger is less key strokes to write log.info than system.out.println, which saves time.

This article is where I learned the logging info: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/logging/java-util-logging-example/