# Single console in eclipse for both Server and Client

Tags: java, console, eclipse-plugin

I am building a client server application using Java Sockets (in Windows XP).
For that I need different consoles for both Client and Server(for Input and Output operations). But in eclipse both share a single console. Is there any plugin or some sort of cheat through which I can do this.

After googling I got this,

http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg17138.html

But, this seems to be only for write operations, not read operations.

Also, I tried the following to launch application manually,
but even this is not working........

```
package mypack;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;


public class MySystem {

    public static void changeStream(String mainFile) throws IOException{

        File temp = new File(".") ;
        String parentPath = temp.getCanonicalPath() ;

        System.out.println(parentPath);

        //creation of batch file starts here
        try{
            File f = new File(parentPath + "\\a.bat") ;
            System.out.println("Created : " + f.createNewFile());
            //f.deleteOnExit() ;

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f) ;

            String str = "java " + mainFile ;
            String batchCommand="@echo off\n"+str+"\npause\nexit";

            char arr[] = batchCommand.toCharArray() ;
            System.out.println(str) ;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
                fos.write(arr[i]) ;
            }
            fos.close() ;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        //creation of batch file ends here

        //execution of batch file starts here                           
        try{
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime() ;

            System.out.println(parentPath + "\\a.bat") ;

            Process p = r.exec(new String[]{"cmd","/k","start a.bat"},null,new File(parentPath)) ;

            OutputStream os = (OutputStream)p.getOutputStream() ;
            System.setOut( new PrintStream(os) ) ;

            System.out.println("Hello");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //execution of batch file ends here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MySystem.changeStream("MySystem") ;
    }
}
```

---

---

Ok Guyz, previously I don't know that multiple consoles are available in eclipse.
But now i got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836981/eclipse-write-to-console), tht's why closing this thread. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only found that you can do that with separate launches in Eclipse (so you need to launch first your server, and then your client).

Unfortunately each Console is then a pane in the Console view, and not its own Console so you have to manually switch, but that is the best I've found so far.

Comment: Also i got the following while googling :-
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F  and  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide    while googling.....